# Альтернатива событию Click или ограничение количества Ajax запросов по 1 клику?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

**День добрый.**

Ситуация такая, есть API для камеры, у этой API есть функционал перемещение камеры по клику на видео. Подключается она примерно таким способом, обрабатывается событием ОнКлик (внутри видео) и уходит на обработку через jQuery:

```
<div class="col s12 center-align" id="videocontainer">
    <img src="" id="video" class="responsive-img" data-camid='' onclick=ptzCenter("center",this)>
</div>
```

В jQuery я снова обрабатываю событие Клика, после чего идёт перерасчёт размеров (высота/ширина) и идёт отправка этих данных через Ajax, НОООО, т.к. 2 раза обрабатывается событие Клик, то Ajax начинает сходить с ума, а точнее делать то, что от него требуется и Ajax запросы отправляются в геометрической прогрессии (кол-во запросов на скрине за 1 клик).

```js
function ptzCenter(camid) {
  $('#video').on('click', function(el) {
    console.log($(this).text("test"));
    camid = $.cookie('lastcam')
    var image = $(el.currentTarget.parentElement).find('img')[0]
    hcoef = image.naturalWidth / image.clientWidth
    wcoef = image.naturalHeight / image.clientHeight
    var fx = Math.round(el.offsetX * wcoef)
    var fy = Math.round(el.offsetY * hcoef)
    var request = $.ajax({
      url: '/axisptz',
      data: 'camid=' + camid + '&posx=' + fx + '&posy=' + fy + '&httpapi=1&ptzCenter=1&',
    })
   return false; // Подобное решение отмены потока Ajax запросов 
  })
}
```

Скрин запросов : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли какая-то альтернатива Клику? (`mousedown` не помог, помог только вызов `alert`, но это не решение, а скорее костыль) или же можно как-то адекватно прекратить Ajax запросы? Что-то аля `xhr.abort();` и `return false;` не помогли (xhr не определен, а при `return false` вообще вырубает другие скрипты или я просто очень криво его выполняю).

Если кому-то важна обработка на Джанге,то вот:

```
if request.GET.get('ptzCenter') == '1':
            if request.GET.get('center') and request.GET.get('fx') and request.GET.get('fy'):
                center = request.GET.get('center')
                x = request.GET.get('fx')
                y - request.GET.get('fy')
                logaction = 'Перемещение по клику'
            else:
                fx = 0
                fy = 0
            params = {'center': fx + fy }
            r = requests.get('http://' + camip + ptzpostfix, params=params)
            return HttpResponse('Ok')
```

Comment: зачем два раза `onclick` обрабатываете?

Comment: Да,я понимаю что это и есть проблема,что клик обрабатывается 2 раза,в этом я и хочу разобраться,как сделать правильно. 1-ый клик нужен,что бы API начало работать и данные передались в DOM и на jQ, а вот без второго клика он никак не хочет отправлять Ajax запросы, пробовал и focus и change и другие события, нет реакции,вот и решил узнать,где я делаю не так.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот так решил я этот вопрос:

```js
function ptzCenter(id) {
  console.log("test")
  video.onclick = function(ev){
    camid = $.cookie('lastcam')
    var image = $(ev.currentTarget.parentElement).find('img')[0]

    hcoef = image.naturalWidth/image.clientWidth
    wcoef = image.naturalHeight/image.clientHeight
    var fx = Math.round(ev.offsetX * wcoef)
    var fy = Math.round(ev.offsetY * hcoef)
    //alert(`${fx} ${fy}`);
    var request = $.ajax({
      url:'/axisptz',
      data:'camid=' + camid + '&posx=' + fx + '&posy=' + fy + '&httpapi=1&ptzCenter=1&',
    })
   }
 }
```

```html
<div class="col s12 center-align" id="videocontainer">
   <img src="" id="video" class="responsive-img" data-camid='' onclick=ptzCenter("center",this)> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас при каждом клике на картинку навешивается новый обработчик клика по `#video`, поэтому обработчики копятся и начинают вызываться несколько раз. Просто уберите, для примера, добавление обработчика из функции `ptzCenter`, у вас все равно будет клик по изображению

```
function ptzCenter(camid) {
    // сразу обрабатываем клик
    console.log($(this).text("test"));
    camid = $.cookie('lastcam')
    var image = $(el.currentTarget.parentElement).find('img')[0]
    hcoef = image.naturalWidth / image.clientWidth
    wcoef = image.naturalHeight / image.clientHeight
    var fx = Math.round(el.offsetX * wcoef)
    var fy = Math.round(el.offsetY * hcoef)
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: '/axisptz',
        data: 'camid=' + camid + '&posx=' + fx + '&posy=' + fy + '&httpapi=1&ptzCenter=1&',
    })
   return false; // Подобное решение отмены потока Ajax запросов 
}
```

Comment: Пробовал данный метод уже,от безысходности,но он сразу ругается на другой скрипт Uncaught ReferenceError: showVideo is not defined
    at SVGGElement.onclick, при том, что данный скрипт стоит выше и должен раньше обрабатываться (он открывает видео с камеры,а если сделать как вы предложили,он даже видео открывать не хочет)

Comment: @БогданСергеевич данный код вообще ни как не связан с вашей ошибкой

Comment: Это я с ошибкой написал (скобки не убрал). Исправив,понял почему такой вариант не актуален, у меня по фильтру EL идет расчет размеров окна и координат клика. Если убрать первую строку,то el is not defined :с

Comment: @БогданСергеевич так откуда вы `el` берете, чему он должен быть равен?

Comment: Вообще, это фильтр в основном коде JS,применяется во всех массивах (основной код JS не мой),ну а сам el фильтр нужен для : фильтровать содержимое массива на основе критериев поиска. Без фильтра выдает ошибку, что переменные не определены, а следовательно, где-то в сайте этот фильтр висит,а вот где - искать долго

Answer (score 1):

> Вот так решил я этот вопрос:

Вы решили неправильно. Обратите внимание, что никакой ajax не посылается на первый клик:

```js
function clickMe() {
  document.getElementById("video").onclick = function(e) {
    console.log("send ajax");
  };
}
```

```html
<button id="video" onclick="clickMe()">Click</button>
```

---

```
<div class="col s12 center-align" id="videocontainer">
   <img src="" id="video" class="responsive-img" data-camid=''> 
</div> 

$("#video").click(function(e){
  ...
});
```

Comment: А это именно то,что мне и нужно, иначе при открытие камеры (самого видео с камеры) в модальном окне он отправляет не нужный мне Ajax запрос, что лишняя нагрузка на поток с камеры. А вот дальше, при повторном нажатии клике по видео, уже идёт перемещение камеры. Ведь основная задача - не нагружать лишним потоком из Ajax запросов камеру,что бы она "не упала")) Но спасибо Вам за вашу внимательность)